# check checkboxes with if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery-mobile, I have a question about handling checkboxes in the group :

I would like to show php page with checkboxes, if the value is set it to true from database, i would like to make checked checkbox in checkbox-group with an if condition.

like :

```
if(foo) {    
 $(checkbox.id).setChecked
 $(checkbox.id).refresh();
}
```

Comment: Questions normally have a question mark.

Comment: Im sorry, this is not even code.. i had to edit it to make it understandable. show us what uve done till now.

Comment: Yes , coz you guys used to help people what you know about. If i would ask something like, how can i know that checkbox is checked , I am sure you all ( giviving minus to me) would answer my question with copy paste for earning points.

Comment: WHOA! no need to be rude here! All you need to do here to get an answer is to put in what you've done till now, your code here n stuff, maybe make a fiddle. Peace.

Comment: You just don't need to answer every questions which you do not know or could not find it on google. If you don't know simply look another questions :) take care ...

Comment: I think they're saying they don't really understand your question. Not that they can't answer it. Implying that people just google the answers is also rude,people here aren't paid to help others,they just do it to be helpful so if they ask for more info it's so you can help us help you. Do you have any other code you can show? I've submitted an answer below as it sounds like you actually want to do this in php as you render the page, not in javascript

Comment: People answer questions and those answers _turn up on Google_. How can anybody Google for a copypasta if they haven't written it yet? I think telling people to not comment on your poor quality question is the _least_ useful way of getting an answer

Comment: @Bojangles , Do you mean that poor question because I did not paste any html or JS code over here. My question is simple I need to trigger checkbox checked values with in if condition. I just need that. If people do not care about the having points, they would not decrease point of my question just because they don't understand it .

Comment: @OnderOZCAN here u go !! http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/6CQgM/

Comment: @hungerpain, You just get it from stackoverflow and it's triggering with button action not if condition ! You just need to understand that i need to do that in if condition to show user preferences ... And why you don't post it as reply ? :) Do you scaring to getting minus my dear?

Comment: I guess you need spoon feeding my friend. Can't you make the stuff in click function to make it work for your if condition? I think you've got it all wrong abt this site. Ppl willnot code for you. TThey'll help you code. Hope you get that

Comment: I really don't care who searching through google and paste the code for getting points over here.I found your link before wrote my question over here. If you need to get more attraction , use your own sentence... @hungerpain

Comment: @OnderOZCAN I would **love** to see what you found on Google before you found my link. I come here to help and it hurts whenppl uuse hate speech here.

Comment: Oh , I did not use any bad word to you. But you gave mine question - , instead of reading very little sentence in order to understand and try to help. If you can read @TommyBS's answer you can understand that my question is not garbage.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using php to render the page, why do you need js to check the checkbox? Just do something like

```
  //in your php
 while($row){ // assuming $row is your database row
   $checked = $row['foo'] == true? 'checked' : '';
   echo '<input type="checkbox" '.$checked.' class="my-checkbox" />';
}

//js in your onload event
$('.my-checkbox').each(function(){
     if(this.checked){
           $(this).refresh();
     }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this can be correct for standard html checkbox format. But assign check value jquery-mobile checkbox I need to use condition to refresh checkbox.id somehow in if () condition ....

Comment: I need to use jquery-mobile because I am using this layout in iOS UIwebView ..

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer. I'd still use the php side to set checked, but then run the js code I've added into your load event to loop through the checkboxes and refresh the item if it is checked. I haven't used jqueryMobile but I'm assuming it has an each method like normal jQuery. But I did look up the refresh() method to figure out what you wanted to do

Comment: Also are you sure the php version doesn't work on it's own? I'd be surprised if you weren't able to set a checkbox to checked initially and the styling wouldn't update. The docs say you only need to call refresh when manipulating with javascript, not if you've initially set checked. This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krrX8/ seems to imply setting it to checked by default does work which means you could do it in your php without the js code I added above

Comment: js refresh function worked for me. Thank you for your help. Also thank your for giving a time to read my little sentence to understand what really i need . Stackoverflow really need you ( Not copy pasting without understanding questions . ) You deserved point ;)